# what happens in logcat when content is copied to clipboard?

Tags: logging, copy-paste

I am trying in vain to identify if and how, in logcat, the events such as "text copied to clibboard" are logged.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it out? Simply use an app that copies something to clipboard and then check the different logcat logs.

Comment: I did and was unable to identify the right strings among the "million" of ones passing by every second, that is why I asked for help. :-D

Comment: All we can do is also look at logcat and check if there is an entry. As logcat always includes the time you can execute the copy to clipboard at a special time you remember and then check the logcat entries directly after that time. In the logcat main section I don't think you will find anything clipboard related unless the app itself logs it.  There is a higher chance in logcat events to find something on clipboard usage. If not then clipboard usage is simply not logged at all.